# How to return multiple array element index values as an Int in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift4

I can't seem to figure out any way to return an element's index value (even if there are two elements of the same type) in an array. For example:

```
var array = ["Apples","Dogs","Monkeys","Cats","Apples"]
```

Since there are two elements with the name, "Apples", I want to return their index value individually as an Int (not an array of Ints). Can someone please help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    for (index, value) in array.enumerated() {
        if value == "Apples" {
            print(index)
        }
    }
```

you can store it in a different variable or store it in array.you will get the index of string "Apple" from the given array. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to return index of item like this -

```
func indexOfElement(element: String) -> Int? {
    while array.contains(element) {
        if let index = array.firstIndex(of: element) {
            array.remove(at: index)
            return index
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

and then use it for array like this

```
var array = ["Apples","Dogs","Monkeys","Cats","Apples"]
```

this while loop will get all indices of the element you are searching for and then you can store them in an array or just print them like code below

```
var index = indexOfElement(element: "Apples") 
while(index != nil) {
    print(index!)
    index = indexOfElement(element: "Apples") 
}
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: Thank you so much, and yes I will have coding :)